# Ignoring Hidden Table Rows in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good Evening.

I am trying to get my formulas to ignore hidden rows in a filtered table.  I have attempted some of the tricks shown here, but I haven't been successful.

The CSV I get from BigFix (network management tool) looks something like:
[image: [Table]]

The applications column lists the applications in the same cell.  As a result, when I do a count function to identify the issues, I have to use a wildcard (I'm searching for the results in a different [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPyLt.jpg)).

[image]

```
=COUNTIF('Input Data'!C:C,"*"&Results!A2&"*")
```

I want to be able to filter the table on the first tab, and have the formula results show up accurately on the 2nd tab.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
I feel more information would help.  The reason I want the "results" tab to update automatically is that I plan to build graphs out of the information on that tab.  I would love to be able to filter the table in the 'input data' to include only Department A and have the graph autoupdate to Department A's info.

The excel files I'm working with have up to a thousand entries, and I'm trying to get graphs I can copy/paste to put into a presentation as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Why not just [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) for A, B and C?

Comment: @Jeeped I added an update to better explain why I am looking for the ability to create a dynamic table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Input Data'!C:C,ROW('Input Data'!C:C)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C:C)),,1))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,'Input Data'!C:C))))
```

In the above formula Restrict the C:C to your actual data range or use a named range to identify the Actual Data Range.

> **Edit**

Above formula should be replaced with 103 instead of 3 as pointed by Jeep

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET('Input Data'!C:C,ROW('Input Data'!C:C)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C:C)),,1))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,'Input Data'!C:C))))
```

In the above formula Restrict the C:C to your actual data range or use a named range to identify the Actual Data Range.

> **Adding Explanation based on OP's Request.**

In the above formula Used Sumproduct() Subtotal() Offset() Min() Row() IsNumber() Search() function combinations for arriving your expected result.

**Row()** - Will get the Row Number of a given range

**Min()** - Will get the Minimum Value of a given Numbers

**Offset()** - Is used to redirect the reference to each cell of a given range.

**Subtotal()** - Is used to find the (un)hidden state of redirected reference.

**Search()** - Is used to find the specific text in a given range (Not case sensitive) will result Number or error.

**IsNumber()** Is Used to check whether search returns Number or error.  So Isnumber will return boolean True/False as result.

**Column-C**    **Column-D**

Data    For Filtering

a   1

b   1

a   1

a   2

a   2

The above data starts from 1st Row with headers in the 1st Row.  Assume that I filtered D column With 1.  Using the below formula will result 2.

=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET('Input Data'!C2:C6,ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)),,1))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",'Input Data'!C2:C6))))

ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6) = {2;3;4;5;6}

MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)) = 2

ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)) **should be read as**
{2;3;4;5;6}-2 = {0;1;2;3;4}

OFFSET('Input Data'!C2:C6,ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)),,1) = 'Input Data'!C2,'Input Data'!C3,'Input Data'!C4,'Input Data'!C5,'Input Data'!C6

SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET('Input Data'!C2:C6,ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)),,1)) **should be read as**

SUBTOTAL(103,'Input Data'!C2,'Input Data'!C3,'Input Data'!C4,'Input Data'!C5,'Input Data'!C6) = {1;1;1;0;0}
Subtotal() arrived the visible state of each (cell) reference.

SEARCH("a",'Input Data'!C2:C6) = {1;#VALUE!;1;1;1}

ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",'Input Data'!C2:C6)) **should be read as**
ISNUMBER({1;#VALUE!;1;1;1}) = {TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}

SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET('Input Data'!C2:C6,ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C2:C6)),,1)) = {1;1;1;0;0}

(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",'Input Data'!C2:C6))) = {TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}

{1;1;1;0;0}*{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE} = {1;0;1;0;0}

SUMPRODUCT({1;0;1;0;0}) = 2

Used Sumproduct() to avoid Array Entry and also to do the Array Formula Task (Looping through the range of cells) and Sumproduct() will result the Sum of the passed values.

Comment: Should that be 103 or is this one of the situations where 3 or 103 both discount hidden rows? @user112802 - See [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) for details on various operations discarding hidden rows.

Comment: @Jeeped, Thanks for correcting me.  It should be 103 as you pointed.  By mistake I made it as 3.  So the formula should be replaced with 103 instead of 3.  Subtotal() is working fine by differentiating it's actual puropse 3 & 103.  It's my formula which given a picture that both are same.  This part is the actual cause for that dilemma (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,'Input Data'!C:C))).  If we ignore that part and multiply it with 1 then we will know the error part highlighted by you =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET('Input Data'!C:C,ROW('Input Data'!C:C)-MIN(ROW('Input Data'!C:C)),,1))*1)

Comment: @user112802, Explanation added in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering the source data, use the Countifs function and add the filter conditions to the Countifs.

Comment: I added an update to my question to help explain why I want the formulas to ignore the hidden rows.  I want to create dynamic graphs based on the filtered table on the first tab, but only after that filtered table has been searched for the specific keywords on tab 2.